# Do I have to build a separate release of my class library for each version of .net?

Tags: .net, version, compatibility

I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, but I haven't found a question that asks this outright.

My product is a set of .NET class libraries. The applications that use them and their config files are entirely out of my control. I had (mistakenly, I believe) thought that if the libraries were built against .NET 2.0, they could be used with later versions. After a recent user problem, I have dug into the situation in more detail, and if I understand correctly, compatibility is only compile-time and not runtime (unless specified in the app config.)

So do I have to build it against each framework version users want to target, or is there a way to produce a class library that is version-independent?

Comment: In general it should work fine... is there a problem you have seen referencing a 2.0 dll from a 4.0 application?

Comment: I had always assumed that 3.5 and 4.0 were reasonably backward compatible with 2.0. You can identify your runtime version using `Environment.Version`

Answer (score 2):

Unless your class library is mixed mode, you *should* be able to use a .NET 2.0 class library from a .NET 4 application with no problems. (I assume you've built "Any CPU" assemblies.) I've done this on many occasions.

You *should* be okay, but if you have a specific error I suggest you put together a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, and include that in your question.

Comment: Ah! My problem seems to be that my test application (which is built along with the product) targeted .NET 2.0. If I build the app targeting .NET 4 and use the class library assemblies targeting .NET 2.0, it works fine.  Thanks for pointing the way; the Microsoft docs made it sound like everything that's built targeting a specific version will only work with that version unless the app.config says otherwise.

Comment: (Sorry about the deleted comment you replied to; my edit to replace it with the text above timed out.)

Comment: @Jim: Have duly deleted my comment. So is all well now?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I was not looking forward to the prospect of explaining app config files to users. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to target your application to use a runtime (.Net Framework) that is different from the one that was used to build your application, you will need to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can specify the target framework in teh app.config file, like this:

```
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```